# Can I access androidmanifest.xml file from my phone?

Tags: android

I have started learning Android . I was wondering if it is possible to access and edit the Androidmanifest.xml file of ANY app installed on my smartphone and edit it on the phone itself so that the changes are reflected back in the app assuming that my phone is rooted. Changes can be anything like hiding apps icon or changing permissions etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely not possible

Comment: @Parth : It won't be possible but yes you can read those androidmanifest file

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it IS possible, but not for ANY app. If you are building your own app(s), then yes! Install [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui) from the Play Store to do it! It has tutorials, but you don't need to pay the money to use the app on your own - just to learn. It is a comprehensive IDE and it runs the app right on your phone!

Comment: @Parth, I haven't played around with importing existing code, but I'm sure it wouldn't be too hard to save your current app's source code on the phone memory and then access it from AIDE.